# Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, updating

I have a table named "users" with some basic fields like name, address, city and mobile.

Now on form load I'm trying to show all the rows in a datagridview as shown below:

```
Dim strConnection As String = "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Customers;Integrated Security=True"
Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
con.Open()
Dim myadapter As New SqlDataAdapter
myadapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select name, address, city and mobile from Users", con)
Dim ds As New DataSet
myadapter.Fill(ds, "Users")
UsersDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Till here its working fine.

Now I would like to update the fields from gridview and tried the below code but it gives me an error as :

***`Update unable to find TableMapping['Table'] or DataTable 'Table'.`***

```
 Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
     Dim cmdbl As New SqlCommandBuilder(myadapter)
     myadapter.Update(ds, "Users")
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here

1) Your example doesn't show a call to GetUpdateCommand()

Try this instead:

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim cmdbl As New SqlCommandBuilder(myadapter)
    cmdbl.GetUpdateCommand()
    myadapter.Update(ds, "Users")
End Sub
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfbedfwf(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfbedfwf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

2) Also, it looks like your SELECT command does not include a primary key column.  You need that so the CommandBuilder can build an effective Update or Delete commmand.

I don't know what your table looks like, but if your primary key column is named ID, then change your original sql (select statement) to this:

```
myadapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select id, name, address, city and mobile from Users", con)
```

3) something looks wrong with your Select command.  Specifically the column "city and mobile".  if that is the name of your column, you might need to put delimiters around it like this:

```
myadapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select id, name, address, [city and mobile] from
```

Users", con)
    'or maybe you meant to say this:
    myadapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select id, name, address, city, mobile from Users", con)